# Node TypeScript file export huge array of objects - compilation fail. Help nedded to fix compilation

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, compilation, large-files

I have a typescript source file on a project

```
 <Project Root path>/spec/SpecEnums.ts
```

This file contains an array of objects (only)
it is a huge array each object has some fields:

```
 export interface ISpecEnums {
 Tag: string;
 Value: string;
 SymbolicName: string;
 Group?: string;
 Sort: string;
 Description: string;
 Added?: string;
 AddedEP?: string;
 Updated?: string;
 UpdatedEP?: string;
 Issue?: string;
 Deprecated?: string;
 DeprecatedEP?: string;
 Elaboration?: string;
 }
```

(the object class defined in a different file
../src/enums/Enums)
the array defined in the file has 27373 lines
of code hardcodded on the file.

```
import { ISpecEnums } from '../src/enums/Enums';
export const ENUMS: ISpecEnums[] = [
{
    Tag: '4',
    Value: 'B',
    SymbolicName: 'b',
    Group: '',
    Sort: '1',
    Description: 'B',
    Added: 'RPOTOCOL.0.1',
 },
 {
    Tag: '4',
    Value: 'S',
    SymbolicName: 's',
    Group: '',
    Sort: '2',
    Description: 'S',
    Added: 'RPOTOCOL.0.1',
 },
 . 
 .
 .
 ];
```

I try to build this project on Visual Studio Code
using a script:

```
 "build": "rimraf ./build && tsc --project tsconfig.json"
```

alternatively:

```
 "compile": "./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc --project tsconfig.json"
```

It fail with error message:

```
 Error: "Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent."
```

I performed some experiments on the file put its end (truncated end of file)
on remark until it gets compiled successfully without an error.
obviously it is only for attempting understand the reason.

I suspect the file is too long to be compiled using tsc compiler (typescript).

```
a. is there a configuration section / parameter to allow larger source files? 
b. can you recommend some troubleshooting to identify the root cause ?
```

Thanks for advance

Comment: did you find a solution? I have the same problem with large file of mock data I want to feed into the tests

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is typescript breaking, since they apparently have some cap on the amount of unions that can be done: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33130.

However let's just put that aside for a second and look at the bigger picture here... "27373 lines of code hardcodded" -> That statement makes me feel conflicted between admiration for your determination and horrified at even reading that statement.

Why are you trying to hard code your entire database as enums... Store it properly in a database and use your data like it's supposed to be used.

Comment: Matriarx - It is a code from github, I have no alternative functional example to learn the system I try to learn from this source.

Comment: Matriarx - It is a code from github, I have no alternative functional example to learn the system I try to learn from this source.I prefer if participants in this conversation put the focus on the issue in question instead of architecture considerations. I need a brute-force solution to make the source I downloaded from github work with typescript (i got it  javascript from git), I can resolve other consideration offline after I resolve this specific obstacle.